# How to do eager loading with search in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do

```
Model::search($_POST['search_text'])->with('user')->get()
```

But this doesn't work, I get the "Method with does not exist" error (just Model::search($_POST['search_text'])->get() does work, or just Classes::where('id',2)->with('user')->get() ).

How can I do eager loading on a search result?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how the search function works, but I think that it returns a key or NULL, and you need a model to eager load. Can you dd() what you got with `Model::search($_POST['search_text'])->get()` ?

Comment: put `with()` as the first method in the chain i.e. `Model::with(...)->search(...)->get()`

Comment: @RossWilson that gives an erro r- Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()

Comment: Can you show how you've defined your `search` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want search at request, then better create in controller function

```
public static function search($request, $query){
    if($request->has('string')){
         $query->where('column', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->get('string').'%');
       }
    }

public function postIndex(Request $request){
    Model::where(function($query)use($request){
        $this->search($request, $query);
    })->with('user')->get()
}
```